# Is Fusion free-evaluation license valid only on one system?

Tags: linux, centos, vmware, centos-7, vmware-fusion

I'd like to evaluate CentOS 7 and 8 with VMware Fusion on Macbooks.
Is the 30 days license good only for one machine, or could I use the same license on multiple machines?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Answer (score 0):

Given there is no registration and therefore they cannot send you a license, it would appear you can install it on as many systems as you wish. The clock will start ticking from the moment you install. The only mechanism which could restrict it, is if there is some form of broadcast/multicast packet, in which case, you can firewall that off.